# The Attribution Problem of Firebase Advertising

Tags: analytics

Both the website and app are integrated with firebase; By visiting our website to directly download and install APK or jumping to the appStore to install the app, how can we know if the source is our website after opening the app

The Android version of the app has integrated firebase, but the source is not associated with the website